# Teensy audio alternative

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, audio, teensy

Can anyone recommend some alternatives to the teensy with capabilities to play multiple audio files.

I have a electronics project with a interactive game it is currently using a couple of button inputs a Li-po battery power source, NFC for detecting accessories, Bluetooth 4.0 for connecting to accessories, nrf24l01 for communication to a laptop, GPS and accelerometer, vibration motors for feedback and a small udisk audio module for playing basic sounds, this all runs off a arduino mega.

We have since decided to make some upgrades mainly to play multiple audio files so we can play effects and trigger sound over them at the same time to improve realism and may like to be able to play announcements over the existing nrf24l01 network to signal start if game and fouls ect.

The teensy looks perfect for this I only really need to play 2 audio sounds at a time but want to know what our options are as the teensy increases cost considerably could the stm32 handle this or perhaps another arm with an audio IC and sd card any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear how long the sound files are and if you want to play 2 sounds overall or if you want to play and mix 2 sounds at the same time.

Some possibilities:

1. [ISD audio player chips](http://www.nuvoton.com/hq/products/isd-voice-ics/isd-chipcorder-family/) from Nuvoton. Definitely the easiest but most limited when it comes to the length of audio.
2. Any microcontroller with DMA and an external DAC
3. Any microcontroller with DMA and a DAC made from a resistor ladder
4. Any microcontroller with DMA and built-in DAC. For example the EFM32GG has an [mp3 player project](https://www.silabs.com/community/projects.entry.html/2015/03/05/mp3_player_demo_usin-wzKI) available. There are also raw audio and Speex demos for this MCU.

Depending on the desired audio lengths the microcontrollers can store the data in internal flash if it is big enough, external SPI flash or SD card. SD card implementation will definitely be the most complex, as you also need to handle the filesystem (eg. FatFS), parse the files etc.